# Questionwith AngularJS ng-repeat and json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Being new to AngularJS it seems certain things should be simple but I reaching out for support on the correct way to retrieve json data using ng-repeat. I've searched through other posts but still cannot solve the problem. What am I doing wrong here?

html:

```
  <html lang="en" ng-app="configApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Configuration Admin</title>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="OrganizationProgramCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="program in programs">{{programs.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var configApp = angular.module("configApp", []);
    function OrganizationProgramCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.programs = [];
        $http.get('data/programs.json')
                .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                    console.log("Data Found");
                    $scope.programs = data;
                });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

json data:

```
{
    "programs": [{
        "title": "MA History"
    }, {
        "title": "MA  Biology"
    }, {
        "title": "MA Chemistry"
    }, {
        "title": "MA Classical Studies"
    }, {
        "title": "MA Liberal Arts"
    }]
}
```

Comment: i think you want `$scope.programs = data.programs;` in your success callback, otherwise you would need to do `program in programs.programs` in your `ngRepeat`. Also you may need to parse the json string to an object, `JSON.parse(data)`. As i do not know if angular does it automatically or not.

Answer (score 1):

You code needs a couple of changes but you're almost there:

```
$scope.programs = data.programs;
```

and (singular program for title

```
<li ng-repeat="program in programs">{{program.title}}</li>
```

Working reference version here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JwmmA5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In your ng-repeat you are assign the current iterator item to a variable called `program` however in your html to are referencing `{{programs.title}}` (programs with an 's')

Change it to this and it should work `{{program.title}}`

Comment: Sweet no worries - good luck with learning angular.  One day it will all just click!

Comment: @jmccommas - don't forgot to mark the correct answer